# Show that $(x_n) $ convergent to 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that if $x_n \geq 0$ and the limit of $((-1)^nx_n) $ exists,  then $(x_n) $ convergent to 0.

I don't have a single clue to solve the problem. I have looking back about monotone sequence,  Cauchy sequence,  and bounded one, but seem don't lead to this. Please help.  Regards

Comment: This isn't true; if $x=-1$ then the limit exists and equals $1$. In all other cases where the limit exists, $|x|<1$, and then the limit follows in the same way as the usual argument about geometric sequences.

Comment: Are you typo there? should it be $(-1)^nx_n$ instead?

Comment: Oh yeah,  mistyped.  I have correct it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that the limit of $(-1)^n x_n$ is $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027020/prove-that-the-limit-of-1n-x-n-is-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a_n\ge 0$ we have, $a_n = |(-1)^n a_n|$. If a sequence converges to L then its absolute value convergers to |L|, due to the continuity of the absolute value function.

In your case  $L=0$ due to the oscillation of $ (-1)^n a_n.$